# VBS to check for unread mail in an Outlook session older than x mins

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, alert

I have a script to run via the task scheduler that checks for unread emails and sends an email alert as shown below.  To further enhance this, I need to be able to check the unread emails and only send the email if they are older than 'x' minutes.

Any thoughts on how best to accomplish this?

Thanks

**see updated code further below with inclusion of suggested code in answer - however this causes a syntax error**

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6
Const olMailItem = 0
dim objOutlook

call checkForUnreadMails


sub checkForUnreadMails()
dim objFolder, objNamespace

'get running outlook application or open outlook
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")  

'get inbox folder
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'send mail if more than 10 mails are unread
if objFolder.UnReadItemCount > 10 then
    sendMail "email@emailaddress.com"
end if

end sub

sub sendMail(address)
dim oItem
Set oItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oItem
     .To = address
     .Subject = "There are unread emails"
     .Body = "Please investigate the mailbox."
     .send
End With
end sub
```

Edited version below:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6
Const olMailItem = 0
dim objOutlook

call checkForUnreadMails


sub checkForUnreadMails()
dim objFolder, objNamespace

'get running outlook application or open outlook
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")  

'get inbox folder
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'look at unread emails
Set UnreadItems = objFolder.Items

'send mail if mails are unread and older than 15 mins
For i = UnreadItems.Count To 1 Step -1
 If TypeName(UnreadItems.Item(i)) = "MailItem" Then
  If DateDiff("n",now, UnreadItems.Item(i).ReceivedTime) > 15 Then
    sendMail "mail@address.com"
    end if
end if
Next

sub sendMail(address)
dim oItem
Set oItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With oItem
     .To = address
     .Subject = "There are unread emails"
     .Body = "Please investigate the mailbox."
     .send
End With
end sub
```

Comment: Never loop through all items in a folder, use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Set UnreadItems = objFolder.Items
For i = UnreadItems.Count To 1 Step -1
 If TypeName(UnreadItems.Item(i)) = "MailItem" Then
  If DateDiff("n",now, UnreadItems.Item(i).ReceivedTime) > 15 Then 
   //Do something
  End If
 End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have tried including this in the script but I am getting a syntax error on line 34, char 1, code 800A03EA.  I'm not sure what I need to change!  See the edited version in the original question above :)

Comment: Never loop through all items in a folder, use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Outlook Object Model from the Task Scheduler - it runs as a service, and no Office app (Outlook included) can be used from a service. Your code will break sooner or later.